# How to bind a checkbox based on the result of a different item

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, materialize, aurelia

i have a list of items loaded on my page from the following ts function as follows

```
export class Test extends Component {
public Stores: Array<StoresModel> = [];
public Items: Array<ItemsModel> = [];
async GetStores() {
        let result = await //gets result from db;
        this.Stores= result.items;
    }
}
```

and then i bind the above result in html as follows

```
    <md-collection>
    <md-collection-item repeat.for="s of Stores" class="accent-text" >
<md-checkbox></md-checkbox> //how do i check this if an item is present for the given store
    ${s.title}
                                
    </md-collection-item>
    </md-collection>
```

which gives me a list of stores as follows

```
Store1
Store2
Store3
```

the output for this.stores looks like this

```
[{storeId:"11111",title:"Store1"}]
[{storeId:"00000",title:"Store2"}]
[{storeId:"12345",title:"Store3"}]
the above works fine.
```

I have another function that gets me all the items from the stores
as follows

```
async items() {
        let Items= await //get items;
        this.items= Items.items;
}
```

and this.items result looks like this

```
[{storeId:"11111",title:"Shoes",id:"df12365"}]
[{storeId:"12345",title:"Clothes",id:"er45896"}]
```

now i want to add a checkbox to the html page ,the question is how do i check the checkbox for the Stores List that has an item present?

so it should look like this

```
[Checked] Stores1
[unchecked] stores2
[checked] stores3
```

i am not sure how to bind the StoreID from this.stores to the storeID of this.items to check the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at the point where you are rendering the checkbox, you are looping through the items and then looping through the stores within each item.  So you have both a store `s` and an item which are known.

You want to see if that store carries that item, so you look through the array `Items`, which contains pairings of stores to items, and see if an entry exists that matches both the current store and the current item:

```
const isChecked = (store: StoresModel, item: ItemsModel) => {
    return Items.some(i => i.id === item.id && i.storeId === store.storeId);
}
```

or

```
const isCheckedId = (storeId: string, itemId: string) => {
    return Items.some(i => i.id === itemId && i.storeId === storeId);
}
```